# How to pass Row of sqlite.swift to another controller using NSNotification

Tags: swift, sqlite.swift

I am using sqlite.swift in my project.

```
let inputdata = row as Row

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("navigateToProductDetail",object: inputdata)
```

I cant pass "inputdata"

inputdata would be AnyObject , in my case its Row

so it throwing error, Help me to solve this or tell me alternate way to pass this row object to another controller

[image]

Comment: Please try to describe what is the intended behaviour and what goes wrong. Is the notification not posted, or is the problem that `inputdata` not is included in the notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it via userInfo like this

```
let userInfo = [ "inputData" : inputdata ]
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("navigateToProductDetail", object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
```

And you can obtain this from `NSNotification` object with `userInfo` property

```
func handleNotification(notification: NSNotification){
    print(notification.userInfo)
    print(notification.userInfo!["inputData"])
}
```

If the `Row` is a `struct` , first you will have to Wrap it into a class object , then you can pass class object to this function.

Create the wrapper class

```
class Wrapper<T> {
    var wrappedValue: T
    init(theValue: T) {
        wrappedValue = theValue
    }
}
```

Wrap your row

```
let wrappedInputData = Wrapper(theValue: inputdata)
let userInfo = [ "inputData" : wrappedInputData ]
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("navigateToProductDetail", object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
```

Get back your inputData

```
func handleNotification(notification: NSNotification){
    print(notification.userInfo)

    if let info = notification.userInfo {
        if let wrappedInputData = info["inputData"] {
            let inputData : Row = (wrappedInputData as? Wrapper)!.wrappedValue
            print(inputData)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the Row ? is it a struct ? or a class ?

Comment: that means that Row can not be casted as AnyObject

Comment: In my case Row is struct

Comment: You can not pass Struct in this way , you will need to create an wrapper for that

Comment: i would appreciate if you share me the code for that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94902/discussion-between-velu-loganathan-and-ogres).